# JavaFX Ant build failed, JDK 10.0.2 Eclipse Photon

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, build, ant

I am trying to build a JavaFX application on Windows 10, Oracle JDK 10.0.2 and Eclipse Photon. The application works, also if I export it as an executable jar it works. For a proper build, I open the "FX Build Configuration", click on "Generate ant build.xml and run".
The build fails with the following error:

```
init-fx-tasks:
    [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

do-deploy:
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\myname\eclipse-workspace\MyProgram\build\build.xml:90: Problem: failed to create task or type javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:resources
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet
```

Browsing the forum I understand the problem is related to the runtime/build environment. The automatically generated `build.xml` states

```
<target name="init-fx-tasks">
<path id="fxant">
    <filelist>
        <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
        <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
    </filelist>
</path>
<taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
    uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
    classpathref="fxant"/>
</target>
```

I installed Oracle JDK with intaller's default paths: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2` and JRE as well `C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2`, but cannot find the `jfxrt.jar` required by `build.xml` in any place in the filesystem, while I can locate `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\lib\ant-javafx.jar`.

In Eclipse Photon, in `Run->External Tools->External Tools Configuration->JRE` the item "Separate JRE" is selected and set to "jdk-10.0.2". 
Does anybody have clue of how to solve this?
Many thanks

Comment: The cause is that the path `${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar` is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bit late, but I don't see answers and it was a bit of a pain to troubleshoot for my own project. This tutorial has most of the right steps https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/part7/, however it comes down to then fixing a few things, like where your ${java.home} variable points to, mine pointed to:

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191

What this means is the jfxrt.jar and ant-javafx.jar cannot be found on those locations, so I changed them to the following:

```
<filelist>
  <file name="${java.home}\..\jdk1.8.0_191\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
  <file name="${java.home}\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar"/>
  <file name="${basedir}"/>
</filelist>
```

This works since I have both JRE and the JDK on my work work computer. Also make sure you have E(fx)clipse installed. If you had resource files, custom images and so make sure that the deployment structure matches your project. I usually create a deploy folder on the root of my project and copy the from the dist folder generated by the build.xml. It can be automated, but I would not worry about it until you can successfully make a deployment... then automate small parts until you have a well working system (just my two cents for what is worth).

Comment: Thanks Alessandro. Yes, I confirm that pointing ant-javafx.jar and jfxrt.jar to the correct location fixes the problem.

Comment: If this solved the problem, could you please mark my answer as the solution? Thank you!